# How do I combine URLs with javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to change the download URL in id = "a1" :

```
<a id="a1" href="http://domainext.com/idman632build9.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download</a>
```

to:

```
domain.com/safelink/?url=http://domainext.com/idman632build9.exe
```

domain.com/safelink/ is the download page on my site

Comment: `document.getElementById` will allow you to get a reference to the html element. `setAttribute` will allow you to change the `href` attribute value.

Comment: 1) get the current href attribute value from the element. 2) concatenate it onto the end of the other URL. 3) write that value back into the href attribute of the element. What have you tried? What are you stuck with? Each of these steps is quite simple and is certainly trivial to research online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the element using `querySelector` and add what you want to the start of existing `href`

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#a1');

a.href = "domain.com/safelink/?url=" + a.href

console.log(a.outerHTML)
```

```html
<a id="a1" href="http://domainext.com/idman632build9.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download</a>
```

Comment: this works, but the page url containing the download button is printed to be like this: `domain.com/page/domain.com/safelink/?url=http://domainext.com/idman632build9.exe`

How to delete: `domain.com/page/` ?

Comment: this works, there was a problem with the cache. thank you @Maheer Ali

Comment: this works very well in accordance with my expectations. But this code can only change one URL. How can all URLs with `id="a1"` tags change, not just one URL?

Comment: @RenomuReza Note that **ids are always unique in whole page**. If you should have `class = a1` for that purpose. For all the elements with same class you can  use `document.querySelectorAll('a1').forEach(x => x.href = "domain.com/safelink/?url=" + x.href)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    const myLinkElement= document.getElementById('a1');
    const currentLink = myelement.getAttribute('href');
    const newLink = "myNewLink";
    myelement.setAttribute('href',`${newLink}?url=${currentLink}`);
```

This is my proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

JS code

```
var extURL = document.getElementById("a1").getAttribute("href");
var appendURL = "domain.com/safelink/?url="
var newURL = appendURL+extURL;

document.getElementById("a1").setAttribute("href",newURL);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `document.getElementById` which is available in every browser and then set its href property.

```js
var a1 = document.getElementById("a1")
var newHref = "domain.com/safelink/?url=" + a1.href
console.log(newHref)
a1.href = newHref
```

```html
<a id="a1" href="http://domainext.com/idman632build9.exe" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Download</a>
```

Comment: @downvoter what is wrong in this answer?